# Magento 2 : How to keep the custom form fields filled in case of validation error Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, register

How to keep the custom form field filled values  in registration page. created one customer custom attribute from magento admin (input text field accountnumber). showing this attribute in frontend, but while doing create account given accountnumber , if we are getting any error , page is loading. First name , last name , mail id are still showing as expected. But i am unable to see custom attribute (accountnumber )value in form . Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you find answer for this?

Comment: Not find any answer...